# JSON-RPC for server-client

Tags: android, json, rpc

I'm trying to build a system it has clients and server, clients must use some methods of server and these methods should return objects. I thought can use JSON-RPC architechture, can anyone help me with this?
( client is android, server is android or linux)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as JSON Client on Androin
http://www.codeforest.net/android-json-rpc-client-and-php-zend-framework-server

And this as php Server (and client to, if you need) http://jsonrpcphp.org/?page=download&lang=en

Good luck

Comment: What about Android client to Java server?

Comment: Really don't know... I find this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957436/how-to-use-android-json-rpc-for-androidclient-javaserver-setup .. Maybe there is something helpful.